# Proper syntax for callback on custom javascript function / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've simplified this down, and yes... I know that fadeIn is a strange example... but that is part of the point.

How do I make a call back function on a custom function - or a function with nothing passed through it... for example - what if there is no argument? [Here is a fiddle to illustrate my confusion -](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/ys7de/)

I have broken up this monster set of callbacks into little groups, and I want to chain them - but I'm definitely missing something...

### jQuery

```
// An example function

function sheriff(speed) {
    $('.thing').fadeIn(speed);
}

$('button').on('click', function() {

    sheriff(1000, function() {
        $('body').css('background-color', 'red');
    });

});
```

### EDIT

This is my actual code, with the proper callback in place. I over simplified with my first example, and it didn't show a complicated enough use - and so - for others I'll leave this here.

### jQuery

```
function pullInSocialButtons(speed, callback) {

    var facebook    = $('.toy-box-top .social-links li:nth-of-type(1)');
    var twitter     = $('.toy-box-top .social-links li:nth-of-type(2)');
    var google      = $('.toy-box-top .social-links li:nth-of-type(3)');
    var email       = $('.toy-box-top .social-links li:nth-of-type(4)');

    facebook.fadeIn(speed, function() {
        twitter.fadeIn(speed, function() {
            google.fadeIn(speed, function() {
                email.fadeIn(speed, callback); // CALLBACK
            });
        });
    });

} // end
```

Then in this other function --->

```
$('.some-thing').fadeIn(500, function() {

    pullInSocialButtons(50, function() {
      setTimeout(function () {

        $('.porthole').fadeIn(500);

      }, 1000);
    });

});
```

Comment: If you want to chain them, have a look at the deferred object.

Comment: What's the problem with the updated code you have posted?

Comment: There isn't a problem. I just wanted to show how I used the answer, because you only put the callback at the end in the case of all these nested callbacks, and I wanted to leave some evidence of how the answer helped me in a more complicated situation.

Comment: @SimonHalsey thanks for that suggestion. Finding useful stuff in promise and deferred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `sheriff`, you can receive the second param as the second parameter like

```
// An example function

function sheriff(speed, callback) {
    $('.thing').fadeIn(speed, callback);
}

$('button').on('click', function() {

    sheriff(1000, function() {
        $('body').css('background-color', 'red');
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2GSZ3/)

Comment: OHHHH !   I see, I see!  Thank you, that was driving me nuts! I remember that now! Thank you.

Comment: I added some more specific code since I oversimplified - and it didn't seem like it would be much help to anyone in the future. If you have a second, let me know if in the new scenario - I placed it well. Thanks.